# web api throwing HttpResponseException and how to receive on wpf client

Tags: .net, wpf, asp.net-web-api

from my wpf client I'm sending async request to the web api which should return HttpResponseException in this scenario, so I tried

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   ...
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Not active" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

WebApi side

```
private void GetData()
{
   try {
      data = RavenSession.Query<myobj>().Take(1024).ToList();
   } catch (WebException) {
         throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, "Database is not online!"));
   }
}
```

again on wpf client I want to fetch `HttpResponseException` so I wrapped first block of code into try catch block

```
try{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       ...
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Not active" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
catch(HttpResponseException e){
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
catch(Exception e){
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

but catch block is not hit at all. I can only access to `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` but this way I cannot return detailed message exception from webservice to the client (I want to display detailed message).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the error message from the [Content property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   ...
} else {
    var errorMessage = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
}
```

And format the string as you want.

Reference: (search for "De-serialize the Response Content" in the article).

[ASP.NET Web Api: Unwrapping HTTP Error Results and Model State Dictionaries Client-Side](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825274/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Unwrapping-HTTP-Error-Results-and)